# Dialog dismiss from other activity

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am using method class for alert dialog and showing it from other activities.
Example I have methods class which have alert dialogue like this .

```
public void showDialog(){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    RelativeLayout but_buy =  dialog.findViewById(R.id.but_buy);
    RelativeLayout but_exit = dialog.findViewById(R.id.but_exit);
    but_exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            ((Activity) context).finish();

        }
    });
    but_buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intentSettingsnew = new Intent(context, SettingsActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intentSettingsnew);

        }
    });
    dialog.show();

}
```

And calling it in `HomeActivity` like

```
methods.showDialog();
```

But I want dismiss it from home activity when user leave that activity. Let me know if anyone can suggest me how can I do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you can declare `Dialog class` as a `class variable` like below:-

```
Dialog dialog;
public void showDialog(){
      dialog = new Dialog(context);
      dialog.show();      
}
```

And then whenever you want to close it just call stopDialog method:-

```
public void stopDialog(){
     if(dialog != null) {
         dialog.dismiss();  
         dialog = null;    
     }
}
```

or

you can check your `top visible fragment and get instance`. If instance is your `dialog then dismiss` it.

Comment: Yeah ! This is fine...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
final Dialog dialog;//declare as global
```

inside on Create

```
    dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
```

then

```
   public void showDialog(){

        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        RelativeLayout but_buy =  dialog.findViewById(R.id.but_buy);
        RelativeLayout but_exit = dialog.findViewById(R.id.but_exit);
        but_exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                ((Activity) context).finish();

            }
        });
        but_buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intentSettingsnew = new Intent(context, SettingsActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intentSettingsnew);

            }
        });


        dialog.show();

    }
```

then create method

```
public void closeDialog(){
 if(dialog != null)
   dialog.dismiss();
 }
```

call your Homeactivity destroy

```
    methods.closeDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

on your activity's

```
class YourActivty extends AppCompat{
```

//make your dialog reference Class level

```
 private Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
```

//your dialog calling method

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){

    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `final` for creating an object of the dialog box.

Now as per your requirement.

Create the global object of `dialog`, not in `showDialog()`. Like:-

```
Dialog dialog;
```

and, in

```
showDialog(){
dialog = new Dialog(context);
```

Now,
to dismiss the dialog you can use

```
if(dialog !=null){
  dialog.dismiss();
}
```

as per your requirement, whether in,

**onPause , onStop, onDestroy**